# Quickest way to decode libstdc&#43;&#43;-6.dll to libstdc++-6.dll

Tags: go

How to decode string

```
"libstdc&#43;&#43;-6.dll"
```

to

```
"libstdc++-6.dll" in golang?
```

Packr2 encodes file libstdc++-6.dll to libstdc&43;+-6.dll  which needed decoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`html` package](https://godoc.org/html) from the standard library.

Its UnescapeString does what you want:

```
html.UnescapeString("libstdc&#43;&#43;-6.dll") // returns "libstdc++-6.dll"
```

You can test it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2umjG7Ortkr)